# SQL MAX OF SUM AT NORTHWIND DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, min

Q: Get the highest endorsement  of employee in which product has highest endorsement for that employee  in northwind db.

What I mean is I need to get result like this:

Adam Iphone 131231(Total endorsement of iphone sold by only adam)

Maria IPad 1233 (Total endorsement of ipad sold by only Maria which she has highest endorsement  as product)

I can the all using the code below. I cant use `MAX` with `SUM`.

```
SELECT  E.FirstName,P.ProductName, SUM(OD.Quantity*OD.UnitPrice) AS [Toplam Satış]
FROM [Order Details] OD 
INNER JOIN Products P ON P.ProductID=OD.ProductID
INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.OrderID=OD.OrderID
INNER JOIN Employees E ON O.EmployeeID=O.EmployeeID
GROUP BY E.FirstName,P.ProductName
ORDER BY E.FirstName,P.ProductName
```

For the one's who doesnt have NORTHWIND
[image: Diagram]

Comment: Please add expected output data and sample data. Most of us may not have Northwind DB.

Comment: do u expect to see max value after sum ? have u tried using cte for this

Comment: i dont know how to use cte but i will try @eray 's solution.

Answer (score 1):

First `SUM(OD.Quantity*OD.UnitPrice)` be a subquery,then you can use subquery getting `MAX`.

You will get the `MAX` With `SUM`

```
SELECT x.FirstName,X.ProductName,MAX(X.Toplam Satış)
FROM
(
    SELECT  E.FirstName,P.ProductName, SUM(OD.Quantity*OD.UnitPrice) AS [Toplam Satış]
    FROM [Order Details] OD 
    INNER JOIN Products P ON P.ProductID=OD.ProductID
    INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.OrderID=OD.OrderID
    INNER JOIN Employees E ON O.EmployeeID=O.EmployeeID
    GROUP BY E.FirstName,P.ProductName
) AS X
GROUP BY X.FirstName,X.ProductName
```

Comment: Ty @daniel but it didnt solve my problem. In fact i tried a solution like your. Even that i tried your solution but the results are same. Maybe i couldnt express my question. 
I need to see all names once and every name should have one product with highest endorsement.

FirstName ProductName MAX SM
Anne Manjimup Dried Apples 44742,60
Andrew Rhönbräu Klosterbier 8650,55
Michael Teatime Chocolate Biscuits 6159,50
Anne Sir Rodney's Marmalade 23635,80
... it going down like this.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that if you have a table like below:

```
FirstName  ProductName  TotalSale
A             Y            10
A             Z            20
B             Z            30
```

then you are expecting to see an output like below:

```
FirstName  ProductName  TotalSale
A             Y            10
B             Z            30
```

Depending on that, could you please try something like that? I think using cte would help you for this problem.

```
;with cte (FirstName,ProductName,TotalSale) as
(
   SELECT  E.FirstName,P.ProductName, SUM(OD.Quantity*OD.UnitPrice) AS [TotalSale]
   FROM [Order Details] OD 
   INNER JOIN Products P ON P.ProductID=OD.ProductID
   INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.OrderID=OD.OrderID
   INNER JOIN Employees E ON O.EmployeeID=O.EmployeeID
   GROUP BY E.FirstName,P.ProductName
   ORDER BY E.FirstName,P.ProductName
)
select cte.FirstName,cte.ProductName,MAX(cte.TotalSale)
from cte
inner join (select c.ProductName,max(c.TotalSale) as Max_sale
            from cte c
            group by c.ProductName) t on t.ProductName = cte.ProductName
                                    and t.Max_Sale = cte.TotalSale
group by cte.FirstName,cte.ProductName
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but result is totally wrong :( 
Result has all names not distinct and every products has same total endorsement.
FirstName ProductName (No column name)
Andrew Zaanse koeken 4358,60
Janet Zaanse koeken 4358,60
Margaret Zaanse koeken 4358,60
Steven Wimmers gute Semmelknödel 23009,00
Andrew Wimmers gute Semmelknödel 23009,00
List is going down like this for all items. 
However i think approaching style is true. I will try to fix this. This question is not vital for me. But I just wanna solve and learn.